# Field indirection using reflection methods

Tags: java, reflection, indirection

Given:

```
public class A {
   public int n;
   public int func(Object arg) {...}
   ...
}

public class B {
    private A myA;
    ...
}

private B myB;
```

When using reflection on `myB` I get the field for `myA`; how can I access the members and methods of `class A` with it?
For example let's say I got a string `"myA.n"` and given object `myB` I need to access `myA.n`

```
Class<?> c = B.class; // or myB.getClass()
Field f = c.getField("myA");
int p = ???????? // reflection for int p = myA.n;
int q = ???????? // reflection for int q = myA.func(new Integer(3));
```

Comment: `myA.class` doesn't work. You need `myA.getClass();`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I have similar reflection **working code** with myA.class. My code actually is a method `private void myMethod(Class<?> c)` and I call it with `myMethod(myA.class);`. But `getClass()` will work too

Comment: Unless you have a class which is *called* `myA`, that is not even valid Java syntax.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Sorry, my mistake. You are right, it should read `A.class` I will edit.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I corrected the code in the question. `myA` is a field of `myB`, so the `Class<?>` object should be of type B.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call `Class.getField()` and iterate through them looking for the correct function.

```
For (Field field : class.getField()) {
  if (field.getName().equals("...")) {
    ...
  }
}
```

The reason for this is that there can be multiple fields with the same name and different parameter types (ie the field name is overloaded).

`getField()` returns  the public field in the class, including those from superclasses.

Comment: Sorry Ahmad, I don't fully understand you. In any case, this is not a complete answer. I would like to see how would code the `???????` in my question, fully.